# #VALUE! Error of sumproduct if formula with "" is in cell

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel table:

```
          A                 B                    C                    D
1                     Purchase Price        Sales Price      Purchase Price > Sales Price
2     Product A            50                    40        =SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B6>C2:C6-10))
3     Product B            60                    65
4     Product C            80                    60
5     Product D            10                    20
6     Product E            50                    30
7
```

With the formular in cell D2 I detect the number of products where the *Purchase Price > Sales Price - 10*.

No I want to add in cell B7 and C7 the following formula:

```
B7 =If(A7="";"";60)
C7 =If(A7="";"";50)
```

and expend the formula in cell D2 to:

```
D2 =SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B7>C2:C7-10))
```

Once I do this the formula in cell D2 gives me a #VALUE! error.
Do you guys have any idea how I can solve this issue and avoid the #VALUE! error?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this `=COUNT(IF(B2:B7>C2:C7-10,B2:B7))` formula to D2 and press **CTRL+ SHIFT + ENTER**.

Note: Pressing CTRL+ SHIFT + ENTER will execute formula like array. If you watch D2 in formula bar you will see it as `{=COUNT(IF(B2:B7>C2:C7-10,B2:B7))}` See how arrays work, they add advantages to simple formulas in Excell

Comment: Hi Elnur, thanks for your answer. It works good. One last question: When I expend your formula for example to row 10 {=COUNT(IF(B2:B10>C2:C10-10,B2:B10))} then it only works if each row contains the formula If(A7="";"";60). In my original sheet there will also some rows which are completely empty. Is there a way to change your formula so it works both with empty rows and rows that contain the formula If(A7="";"";60)?

Comment: Here is the formula, Do not forget to press CTRL+ SHIFT + ENTER.
=COUNT(IF(ISNUMBER(B2:B10),IF(B2:B10>C2:C10-10,B2:B10)))

Answer (score 0):

SUMPRODUCT must have values. Change your B7 and C7 to:

```
B7 =If(A7="";0;60)
C7 =If(A7="";0;50)
```

You can use conditional formatting, “Format only cells that contain Cell Value equal to 0” to make the cell appear empty.

Comment: Hi Jason, the cell hast to be empty with "". I cannot use the fix with 0.

Comment: If you're using sumproduct to calculate and average, zeros will throw off that formula. for example, =SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($E2:$Z2),3)=2)*($E2:$Z2))/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($E2:$Z2),3)=2)*($E2:$Z2<>""))

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is that cells B7, C7 do not contain numerical values.

So, using a zero rather than blank cell in B7 and C7 where the product name is blank (per below) will stop that error from occurring. Would this change be acceptable for your purposes? Is else dependent on those cells being blank rather than 0?

```
B7 =IF(A7="";0;60)
C7 =IF(A7="";0;50)
```

Comment: Hi Robyn, the cell has to be empty with "". I cannot use the fix with 0.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited because previous solution was incorrect.]

This is a bit ugly and there might be a better solution, but hopefully it will give you a direction to start:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(IF(ISTEXT(B2:B7),B2:B7+0,B2:B7)>IF(ISTEXT(C2:C7),C2:C7-10,C2:C7-10)))-SUMPRODUCT(--(ISTEXT(C2:C7)*1))
```

This uses 2 calls to SUMPRODUCT.

The first is used to avoid the #VALUE! error, but it counts blank cells as fulfilling the condition every time, so it returns a value that is too high.

This second call to SUMPRODUCT corrects this problem by subtracting the number of rows with blanks.

I have not been able to come up with a simpler solution, though I remain convinced there must be one.

Comment: Hi Eli, I tried your solution. It eleminates the #VALUE! error but it does not count correctly.

Comment: @Michi You are correct. The ISBLANK is not working as I thought. After some research I have edited my answer, above.